# magento: trying to decipher level-top

Tags: menu, navigation, magento-1.9, toplevel

I am trying to understand the flow of how the nav bar is being formed in magento and came across this line in topmenu.phtml that i could not figure out.

```
<?php $_menu = $this->getHtml('level-top') ?>
```

I get how childblocks are called, but where is 'level-top'? Seems like a special key word. Can anyone explain where is this defined and how this is linked to the top nav?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is a bit weird but it boils down to the following:

The call `$this->getHtml('level-top')` refers to the block class `Mage_Page_Block_Html_Topmenu` (`$this` is an instance of that class) with the method inside:

```php
public function getHtml($outermostClass = '', $childrenWrapClass = '')
{
    Mage::dispatchEvent('page_block_html_topmenu_gethtml_before', array(
        'menu' => $this->_menu,
        'block' => $this
    ));

    $this->_menu->setOutermostClass($outermostClass);
    $this->_menu->setChildrenWrapClass($childrenWrapClass);

    if ($renderer = $this->getChild('catalog.topnav.renderer')) {
        $renderer->setMenuTree($this->_menu)->setChildrenWrapClass($childrenWrapClass);
        $html = $renderer->toHtml();
    } else {
        $html = $this->_getHtml($this->_menu, $childrenWrapClass);
    }

    Mage::dispatchEvent('page_block_html_topmenu_gethtml_after', array(
        'menu' => $this->_menu,
        'html' => $html
    ));

    return $html;
}
```

--> `$outermostClass` holds the value `top-level`

From there you see the call to `$renderer->toHtml()` where `$renderer` is an instance of `Mage_Page_Block_Html_Topmenu_Renderer`.

```php
protected function _toHtml()
{
    $this->_addCacheTags();
    $menuTree = $this->getMenuTree();
    $childrenWrapClass = $this->getChildrenWrapClass();
    if (!$this->getTemplate() || is_null($menuTree) || is_null($childrenWrapClass)) {
        throw new Exception("Top-menu renderer isn't fully configured.");
    }

    $includeFilePath = realpath(Mage::getBaseDir('design') . DS . $this->getTemplateFile());
    if (strpos($includeFilePath, realpath(Mage::getBaseDir('design'))) === 0 || $this->_getAllowSymlinks()) {
        $this->_templateFile = $includeFilePath;
    } else {
        throw new Exception('Not valid template file:' . $this->_templateFile);
    }
    return $this->render($menuTree, $childrenWrapClass);
}
```

This method now loads the template file into the `$includeFilePath` variable, in my case `/vagrant/app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/page/html/topmenu/renderer.phtml` (depending on the theme you use).

I couldn't spot any use of `$outermostClass` with the value `top-level`.